# @pnp/sp - send email function returns 404

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, pnp

Just wondering if I could get some help. I built a small webpart that sends an email. On my local workbench it works fine however when I deploy to production

Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [404] Not Found ::>

My Import

```
import { sp,  EmailProperties } from "@pnp/sp";
```

My OnInit establishes context

```
 public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then(_ => {
      // establish SPFx context
      sp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context
      });

    });
  }
```

Send email

```
  const emailProps: EmailProperties = {
          To: ["test@myorganisation.com"],
          Subject: "This email is about...",
          Body: "Here is the body. <b>It supports html</b>"
        };

        sp.utility.sendEmail(emailProps).then(_ => {
          console.log("Email Sent!");
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, stupidity on my part.

Correct code is:

```
sp.setup({
    spfxContext: this.props.context
});
```

Comment: Hi Lori, I have the same issue. But when I add this.props.context. It comes up with an error Property props does not exist on type "MyWebPart". Can you share  you code